# Restarting shell for miniconda

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Sorry for the really weird title, wasn't sure how to frame the question. I am trying to install MiniConda, and it tells me that after I run the shell file, I need to "close the terminal" and restart it to run any `conda` commands. True to their word, if I run any `conda` commands, it does not work - not until I restart the terminal.

Okay, cool... how do  I replicate that in a shell file? If I have a shell file that runs the `miniconda.sh` file, then immediately needs to run some `conda` commands, how do I have it "close itself" or something so I can run these commands?

So, I would want it to look something like this:

```
sh miniconda.sh
restart shell ??
conda ...
```

Comment: have you tried just opening a new terminal?

Comment: No, tbh. But I want this shell file to be able to run conda commands. So... something like what I updated @ravery

Comment: if you close the terminal it is in the script will stop. that is why i ask if opening a new terminal will allow conda commands to be run in the new termnal

Comment: @ravery Explain your thought proess, not sure how that solves anything. Also, it may help to know that I have a file that runs this install file that runs the miniconda.sh installer. a.sh -> b.sh -> miniconda.sh. a.sh installs many things, b.sh deals with minconda install and config, miniconda.sh just installs miniconda

Comment: Without seeing the contents of the `miniconda.sh` file it's hard to say - but at a *guess*, the closing and reopening of the terminal is likely to ensure that any shell environment files that have been modified are re-read. The alternative may be to *source* the file rather than simply running it.

Comment: if opening a new terminal is sufficient, then you script can launch a new process in a new terminal.

Comment: @steeldriver can you explain that? And I can link you the shell file.... but its long... like 84MB long...

Comment: @JohnLexus OK so it sounds like `miniconda.sh` actually unpacks a binary acrchive - in which case sourcing it is not the answer. However there's no reason AFAIK to start a new *terminal* inorder to start a new *shell*; you can just type `bash` to do that.

Comment: Could this `miniconda.sh` be a 'once-in-a-lifetime' action i.e. you have to run it once so that it configures paths, decompresses files ... After having done this once you can enter your `conda` commands right away. Did you try that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you installed to `$HOME/miniconda` (adapt the paths to your exact setup!), for the `conda` commands to be found immediately after the installation you need to:

1. change your `PATH` variable to include `$HOME/miniconda/bin`

   ```
   export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
   ```
2. `source` the activation script called `activate`

   ```
   source "$HOME/miniconda/bin/activate"
   ```

This will make it possible to execute `conda` commands without running a new shell. If you run the installer without the `-b` option it will add those two commands presumably to your `~/.bashrc`, which is loaded when you open a new terminal (or start a new `bash` shell). Therefore a simple `source "$HOME/.bashrc"` might do the trick as well.

Source: [conda.io](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html#install-macos-silent)